# Spring Security Authentication is not working as expected in my configuration

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have configured spring authentication as below and its not working as expected

```
<sec:http auto-config="true">
    <!-- Restrict URLs based on role -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="pages/login.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/css/style.css" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
     <sec:intercept-url pattern="pages/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <!-- Override default login and logout pages -->
    <sec:form-login login-page="/login.jsp" 
                         default-target-url="/pages/products.xhtml" 
                         authentication-failure-url="/login.html?login_error=1" />
    <sec:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login.jsp" />
</sec:http>
```

On server start up i have been redirected to login.jsp ,if i use login form i am redirected to  products.xhtml so far fine but if i directly access products.xhtml , it just allowing me to access the product.xhtml(Even after closing the broser or even on server restart) instead of redirecting to login.jsp . Could anyone just me what i am missing exactly?

Thanks & Regards
Vijay

Comment: Maybe you haven't logged out still got a valid session?

Comment: @micha I logged out. I tested directly accessing the products.xhtml as soon as server restarted its allowing me to access instead of redirecting to the login form

Comment: Have you added the spring security filter in web.xml?

Comment: @Mich yes as  <listener>
  <listener-class>
   org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
  </listener-class>
 </listener>
 <filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

 <session-config>
  <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
 </session-config>

Answer (score 1):

Your patterns and URLs aren't consistent. You have "/login.jsp" for the login page and "pages/login.jsp" in the `intercept-url` pattern.

Try using:

```
<http pattern="/css/**" security="none">

<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" 
                     default-target-url="/pages/products.xhtml" 
                     authentication-failure-url="/login.html?login_error=1" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login.jsp" />
</http>
```

The debug log for a particular request will explain exactly why it is or isn't secured.

Comment: though its not working. I tried so many ways though i could access the rest of files i guess its a bug in spring security.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure** you do not have a Cookie or a valid session...