# JSF and Spring securtiy Integration

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-mvc, spring-security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spring Security Authentication is not working as expected in my configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259780/spring-security-authentication-is-not-working-as-expected-in-my-configuration)

I tried integrating JSF and spring security i spent almost a day but there is no result

Developed an application using JSF,Spring MVC and Primfaces. I am almost done with my requirements, at the end i planned to integrate the spring security but i could n't and i did enough search on net. I feel it may be bug in related framework.

If anyone of you came across the same please post the solution. I post my approach over here

**Step 1:**
Created Login.jsp(to have customized login page)
**Step 2:**
Added below code in my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Step 3:**

Created Springsecurity.xml

```
<sec:global-method-security
    secured-annotations="enabled" />
<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
    once-per-request="false">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="pages/secured/**"
        access="ROLE_USER" />
    <sec:form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
        default-target-url="/pages/secured/products.xhtml"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.html?login_error=1" />
    <sec:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login.jsp" />
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider>
        <sec:user-service>
            <sec:user name="vijay" authorities="ROLE_USER" password="vijay"/>
        </sec:user-service>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

Executed the application and got the login.jsp as first page since i defind in web.xml. On login authentication its forwarding to the Products.xhtml but i could even access the rest of pages which all are comes under the secured folder with out logging in.

Please suggest a better approach or other alternatives.

Comment: For your access attribute have your tried.

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/pages/secured/**"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your access attribute have your tried.  Your first slash was missing in the pattern.

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/pages/secured/**"
    access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Now its redirecting me to login.jsp if i access secured pages (after modifying <sec:form-login login-page="/pages/unsecured/login.jsp") but if i login now this page is redirecting me to /pages/unsecured/j_spring_security_check but it should not be.

Comment: not sure why it would be going to that page but you could set the property always-use-default-target="true" on the form-login to go to the default.

Comment: yeah i tried but still its happening so.anyway your answer was really helpful